# JSInterop.Json.Deserialize is losing milliseconds from DateTime objects

Tags: json, blazor

In my Blazor 0.9.0 project I have a large json string for a list of objects with DateTime property including milliseconds. This is passed to my .cshtml file via Ajax and I call Microsoft.JSInterop.Json.Deserialize on the string. This deserializes well except the DateTime objects lose their milliseconds. For JsonConvert this can be rectified by using JsonSerializerSettings DateParseHandling. How do we do this in Blazor?

```
var json = "{\"timestamp\":\"2019-03-01T12:22:26.102Z\"}";
```

I expect this to be deserialized to 01/03/2019 12:22:26:102 but actual result is 01/03/2019 12:22:26

Comment: I guess you can use Newtonsoft.Json in Blazor...

Comment: That Z Iw/o a space) is maybe not so standard - did you check what the other direction, serialization from a DateTime(Offset) produces?

Comment: going to check it out right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was unfortunately having to create a string representation of the Date field to maintain the milliseconds after deserialization. Neither NewtonSoft 12.01 nor JSInterop currently keep milliseconds if implemented within Blazor for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Blazor uses [SimpleJson](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json), not NewtonSoft. That also affects `Http.GetJsonAsync<T>`.

I have had it break on me for some rather normal looking Json returned from an API ([randomuser.me](https://randomuser.me/) is an example).

I just added the NewtonSoft package, and used the HttpClient to download the results as a string.

Comment: I actually did use NewtonSoft in Blazor pre 0.7 and it had problems with the most basic of tasks. I will try add it again and see how it performs. Will mark as answer if it works.

Comment: I have noticed too that Http.GetJsonAsync<T> breaks on db calls with more than a few hundred records at the moment - this is a known issue apparently. I have had to switch Http.GetAsync() for larger calls.

Comment: NewtonSoft has same issue even when using JsonSerializerOptions - Date is passed in via json correctly including milliseconds. Deserialize loses the milliseconds. Will have to modify the call to return only strings I guess.