# What type of object does DotNet.invokeMethod pass in c# method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I'm using Blazor(3.0.0-preview4) and trying to pass an object from javascript through `DotNet.invokeMethod`. I tested this way and it succesfully passes simple types (strings, int). But if i pass JS object, i get weird object type
[image]
I can write it to Console.WriteLine, it looks like JSON, but not string.[image]

So i cant make anything with this, i can't even parse it and there is no information about SimpleJson assembly from Microsoft. How can i deal with this type?

Thanks in advance.

Code example
Blazor:

```
    [JSInvokable]
    public static void SetPlayerState(object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(args[0].GetType().Name);
    }
```

JS:

```
  window.cInvoke = (methodName, json) => {
    DotNet.invokeMethod("ui", methodName, JSON.parse(json));
  };
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found that blazor uses [this library](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json)

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504537/8086153)
[Related issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7908#issuecomment-479564196)

Answer (score 3):

The DotNet.InvokeMethod will send a JSON string as you see in your WASM console log to your JSInvokable method in the Blazor .razor page.

To deserialize it in the blazor page use

```
[JSInvokable]
public static void SetPlayerState(string msg)
{
    var deserialized = Microsoft.JSInterop.Json.Deserialize<myobject>(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is not JSON string as args[0].GetType().Name returns not string and not object. I made it works by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerState>(args[0].ToString())` (i used json.net as json library from microsoft cant convert types such as int -> uint and so on)

Comment: And its only workaround of converting this weird type

Comment: JSON.parse in your JS will create an object from your parameter "json" string if it is a json string - you should send just a string if you want to receive just a string in the JSInvokable. You could use JSON.stringify to convert your object to string before sending to JSInvokable. At least then you would know you will be receiving a string.

Comment: yes, just want to reduce (de)serialization's count to improve perfomance.